# How to use Validation as a required field check. - SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I ended up owning some older content types ( namely checkboxes ) that refuse to let me change them to required fields.
I had made them required via SharePoint Designer 2010, SharePoint Manager and yet it still doesn't comes as required. Someone made into a Content type Group and something seems corrupt. I saw some workarounds like changing the check box to a text field, etc. But there are too many records that I do not want to mess with.

Is there a way to use validation to check if [CheckboxA] = was selected ?
The default is no. Maybe there is a crafty way to detect that it was selected, if not it will give them a  "required field" prompt.

Comment: Yes, you cannot change Required property of the boolean field in the content type in the UI. But have you tried to set that [Required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldlink.required.aspx) property of the FieldLink throuth the PowerShell. I works very well ussually.

Comment: Hello and thanks. Can you please point me to the commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot change Required property of the Boolean field in the content type in the UI. But have you tried to set that `Required` property of the `FieldLink` through the PowerShell. I works very well usually.

```
$w = get-spweb "Your Site Url"
$ct = $w.ContentTypes["Your Content Type Name"]
$fl = $ct.FieldLinks["Your Field Internal Name"] #important to use internal name
$fl.Required = $true
$ct.Update($true) #to save and push changes to list
```

When you should make sure if content type is really updated in your list. Also you can do the same on the list content type directly, like here http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_28088104.html